# mysql - Search by search tags from junctional table, sort results by number of matches and put most matches on the top - solution?

Tags: mysql, select, count, match, sql-order-by

I have a relational database with three tables:

```
hieroglyphs           hieroglyph_has_search_tag           search_tags
-------------------   ---------------------------------   -------------------
| id | hieroglyph |   | hieroglyph_id | search_tag_id |   | id | search_tag |
-----+-------------   ---------------------------------   -------------------
```

I want to create a query that will allow me to search for hieroglyphs with one or multiple search tags, sort and group results by the number of matches (those hieroglyphs with most matches should be first on the list) and those with the lower number of search tags will occupy lower rows.
This is an example of how it result should look (search tags entered: `man, sitting, arms up`):

```
+----+---------+
| A1 | man     |
| A1 | sitting |
| A1 | arms up |
| A2 | man     |
| A2 | sitting |
| A3 | man     |
+----+---------+
```

And after that to get something like this:

```
+----+---+
| A1 | 3 |
| A2 | 2 |
| A3 | 1 |
+----+---+
```

This is what I came to with MySQL query:

```
SELECT hieroglyphs.hieroglyph, search_tags.search_tag
FROM hieroglyph_has_search_tag
JOIN hieroglyphs ON hieroglyph_has_search_tag.hieroglyph_id = hieroglyphs.id
JOIN search_tags ON hieroglyph_has_search_tag.search_tag_id = search_tags.id
WHERE search_tag = "man" OR search_tag = "sitting" OR search_tag = "arms up"
```

I read that I should use `COUNT()`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, but I don't find the solution on how to implement those for my MySQL query to work as I want. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by hieroglyph` and aggregate with COUNT(*), then order by that COUNT(*) descending:

```
SELECT h.hieroglyph, COUNT(*) counter, 
  group_concat(s.search_tag) tags
FROM hieroglyph_has_search_tag hs
JOIN hieroglyphs h ON hs.hieroglyph_id = h.id
JOIN search_tags s ON hs.search_tag_id = s.id
WHERE s.search_tag IN ('man', 'sitting', 'arms up')
GROUP BY h.hieroglyph
ORDER BY counter desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4hYGVo1tRrMtwB4GPnBFvB/2).
Results:

```
| hieroglyph | counter | tags                |
| ---------- | ------- | ------------------- |
| A1         | 3       | sitting,arms up,man |
| A2         | 2       | man,sitting         |
| A3         | 1       | man                 |
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. It works like a charm. Thank you. Do you know how I can step further and concatenate search tags in the the 3rd column for particular row - for ```A1``` it would be ```man, sitting, arms up```?

Comment: Thank you, this is a very elegant solution, and it works as it should. You were of great help.